# BackboneJS $el.html() doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: jquery, dom, backbone.js

I'm having some trouble updating my AppView's $el HTML content.

When initialising my AppView things work as expected. The `render()` function renders the `RoomPickerView`'s element inside the `#content` div, as is to be expected because the state variable is initialised with 'pickRoom' as it's value.

The problem arises when `render()` is called again from within the `handleCheckRoomResult()` function. The expected behaviour is that `#content`'s html is replaced with the `PlayerCharacterView`'s element, but instead nothing changes and I'm still presented with the previous HTML content (the room picker's).

If I log AppView's `$el.html()` at the end of the call to `render()` it displays the correct HTML, but somehow this does not change the actual DOM.

Below is the code for my AppView, and my full application code (which at the moment is not that much more) can be found [in this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WMk4gyNs).

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#content',

state: 'pickRoom',
roomToken: '',
character: {},

initialize: function() {       
    console.debug('Initializing AppView');

    this.characters = new PlayerCharacterCollection();

    this.characters.add(new PlayerCharacter({name: 'George', race: 'Elf', klass: 'Blacksmith'}));
    this.characters.add(new PlayerCharacter({name: 'Amy', race: 'Human', klass: 'Sorceress'}));

    this.roomPickerView = new RoomPickerView();
    this.characterPickerView = new PlayerCharacterPickerView({collection: this.characters});

    socket.on('check_room_result', this.handleCheckRoomResult.bind(this));

    this.render();
},

handleCheckRoomResult: function(data) {
    if (data.result) {
        this.roomToken = data.token;
        this.state = 'pickCharacter';
        this.render();
    } else {
        console.warn('No room with token ' + data.token + ' exists!');
    }
},

render: function() {
    var htmlString = '';

    if (this.state === 'pickRoom') htmlString = this.roomPickerView.render().$el.html();
    if (this.state === 'pickCharacter') htmlString = this.characterPickerView.render().$el.html();

    console.log(this);

    console.log(this.$el.html());

    // this.$el.html(htmlString);
    $('#content').html(htmlString);

    console.log(this.$el.html());
}
});
```

As you can see I already tried to replace the `this.$el.html(htmlString);` call with `$('#content').html(htmlString);`, hoping that that at least would offer a temporary solution, but still no change to be seen in the DOM.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? I'm out of guesses here :(

**EDIT:**

So my DOM structure looks like this when initialising the page:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content" class="player">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I just checked my DOM and that `#content` div disappears completely and I don't know why... When I set my AppView's element to `$('#wrapper')` all works fine =\ Can anyone explain why that is?

Also, thanks for the comments thus far :D

Comment: Is element available in DOM and ID is unique? Could you check it using: `console.log($('[id=content]').length);`

Comment: Have you checked that htmlString contains what you think it should when re rendering?

Comment: @KyleNeedham: yes, the htmlString contains exactly what I expect it to. Also, see my edit :) Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: can you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DaA5L/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaA5L/1/) from the code in your PastePin, I figured it out!

The problem is in your RoomPickerView. You set the `el` to "div" when you meant to set the `tagName`:

```
var RoomPickerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div'....
```

Should be

```
var RoomPickerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div'...
```

---

Also, a tip on making your `AppView.render()` a bit cleaner, do something like this:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.view().render().el );
},

view: function(){
    return this.state == 'pickRoom' ? this.roomPickerView : this.characterPickerView
}
```